# Movie or Show from late 80's/90's where young adults discover they are "cyborgs"

Tags: story-identification

While watching TV in the early 90's I stumbled across a movie or show, and there was a scene where two teenagers/young adults, 1 male and 1 female, begin removing the skin on their arms or wrists to discover wiring underneath. My mom quickly changed the channel, however this scene has been burned in my mind for decades. It may have been only the girl removing her skin, and the scene may have been shot in a closet?

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and [edit]ing in any extra details, you've got a pretty good bit of details going but just see if you can remember any more

Comment: Was it live action or animated?  You use the word "discover" - does this mean one or both people were surprised to find out there was wiring under the skin?  Do you remember the channel and/or timeslot?  Unfortunately, with only one scene like this, it could've been a one-off episode of something like The X-Files or an anthology show like Twilight Zone, which makes it a lot harder to pin down an answer.